# Save the values of Surface function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix, dictionary

I use the surf function in MATLAB in order to create a 3D map.

This map is created by 2 vectors and for each combination of their values I have a third one that creates the surface.

Is there a way to save for each iteration these sets of three values somehow?

What I want to achieve is to have a matrix which will be as a map for every possible combination of these values.

I've made some efforts with 3D matrices but I made it even more complex and I had many errors because of the dimensions.

Comment: Please give some small example, and describe what you want to obtain. Why do you want to save the values of the surface function, when you already have the values stored in vectors?

Comment: Your "third one" `z` should be a matrix, not a vector, if you work with `surf`, isn't it? Then `z(idx_x, idx_y)` already provides you with a lookup.

Comment: I wanted to obtain a database with a mapping for the there variables that con sited the surface so I could make triplets of each combination of these variables. Finally I did with a 2D matrix and 2 for loops. Thanks for the answers though.